# Unable to connect DJI RC N1 to Raspberry Pi 4 running Lineage OS

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to connect DJI RC N1 to RPI 4 (LineageOS 20/Android 13) for a project. I use GPIO to power RPI 4 to leave the usb c port open. But when I plugged dji rc to usb c port, the system cannot find it at all. Neither DJI Fly app nor MSDK sample app can see the RC.

I saw that some web pages said the RPI 4 needs to and then added "dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=otg" in the config-users.txt still to no avail.

Any ideas how to solve/troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.